# How to combine all the arrays which are inside another array and delete the last symbol in each word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

There is a 2 dimensional array:

```
    let userGroup = [
    ['user1-', 'user2-', 'user3-'],
    ['user4-', 'user5-', 'user6-'], 
    ['user7-', 'user8-', 'user9-']
];
```

How to make a single array from it and delete the symbol "-" after each element?

So the output will be: ['user1, 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6', 'user7', etc...]

And also how to write a code which will do the same but with any number of inner arrays? For example if the "userGroup" array had more unexpected inner arrays with more users (['user11', 'user12', 'user13] etc.), what is the way to write a function which take the "userGroup" array and will do the same (delete the last element "-" in each element and combine all the elements in inner arrays into one array)?

Answer (score 2):

Reduce is one way, can use also the new-ish [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method; by default it flattens only to single level but possible to define depth

```
userGroup.flat().map(item => item.slice(0, -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 console.log(userGroup.reduce((acc, curr)=> [...acc, ...curr], [])
    .map(el => el.replace('-','')));
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one liner, consider:

```js
const mapped = userGroup.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c), []).map(s => s.slice(0, s.length-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[].concat.apply([], userGroup).toString().split('-,');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is the one you are looking for

```
userGroup.flat()
```

and then you will have the flat array for your array of arrays.

Then user the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the values as you like

```
userGroup.flat().map(m => m.replace('-', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need few things to achieve your goal.

1. [**.replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const u = 'user1-';

console.log(u.replace('-', ''));
```

2. [**.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const u = ["user1-", "user2-", "user3-"];

const m = u.map(i => i.replace("-", ""));

console.log(m);
```

3. [**.flat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const u = [
  ["user1-", "user2-"],
  ["user3-", "user4-"]
];

console.log(u.flat());
```

So, combing all the 3 methods in a single statement, the below is the code:

```js
let userGroup = [
  ['user1-', 'user2-', 'user3-'],
  ['user4-', 'user5-', 'user6-'],
  ['user7-', 'user8-', 'user9-']
];

   let grouped = userGroup.flat().map(item => item.replace('-', ''));
   console.log(grouped)
```